# Install Vim and Latex suite

Tags: editors, vim

Good Afternoon All,

I am trying to install Vim and Latex suite to work on my latex project.

I need help with installing this properly on Mac OS X Lion. I have already installed MacVim.

To setup Vim-Latex I am using instructions provided [here](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=download&title=Download). According to instructions

1. I have downlaoded vim-latex-1.8.23-20120125.768-git8b62284.tar and
   extracted to ~/.vim directory.
2. I have created file ~/.vimrc with
   content from [recommended settings](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/recommended-settings.html)
3. I have created file
   ~/.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim with content from [recommended settings](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/recommended-settings.html).

**Install the help files**
To install the included latex-suite.txt and latexhelp.txt files as vim help files, start vim and do the following:
helptags ~/.vim/doc

How do I do this step, because from terminal I get following error

```
Khurrams-MacBook:.vim kmajeed$ helptags ~/.vim/doc/  
-bash: helptags: command not found
Khurrams-MacBook:.vim kmajeed$
```

**How can I make sure LATEX is setup and working fine for me?**

Answer (score 4):

`helptags` is not a shell command, it is a `vim` command.  You need to call it from inside `vim`.  Start `vim` and type

```
:helptags ~/.vim/doc/
```

(notice the colon).

Comment: I executed the command from vim, cursor goes to the top of editor window. But I din't see any confirmation. Is it normal?  **How can I make sure LATEX is setup and working fine for me?**

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no confirmation.  Try `:help latex-suite` to see if the help tags were generated correctly.  Other than that, to see if your setup is working, the best way is to open a tex file. You should automatically have TeX syntax highlighting, and the gvim menus should contain the latex-suite commands.  You should have `TeX-Suite`, `TeX-Environments` and few other menus like that.  Using the LaTeX suite compile command (I believe the default is `\ll`) should compile your file, the view cammand (`\lv`) should launch a dvi or pdf viewer with your document in it.