# Problem with \cite{ F9 in VIM

Tags: bibtex, citing, vim, vim-latex

I am working on Linux Ubuntu, and work on VIM 8.2.

The latex syntax is working when I open a .tex document, but when using \cite{ and F9, nothing happen.

Futhermore, I noticed that the following commands does not work in VIM. Which make me think that vim-latex is maybe not installed properly.

```
:helptags ~/.vim/doc 
:help latex-suite.txt
```

I have tried to re-install vim-latex several times, and it still does not work. Would anyone have an idea what can cause this problem?

For the installation, I have followed the instructions given in the vim-latex tutorial below:
http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=download&title=Download

My .vim file look like this:

```
autoload  bundle  ftplugin  pack  plugged  vim-latex  vim-latex-1.10.0
```

Futhermore, I have tried to install vim-latex with Vimplug.
My .vimrc file is attached.
https://newtextdocument.com/c5697f8c94

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thank you! I have been reading the forum for a while before posting for the first time!

Comment: I have posted twice on Tex.SE, and noticed that both questions have been down voted.

It has not happened to me on any other StackExchange forum, and might be due to a problematic formulation of my questions, or irrelevant subject.

Please let me know what is wrong with this question, so I might improve in the future. Thank you.

Comment: A guess would be that... I don't use vim-latex, and can't see what you think F9 in the plugin is supposed to do...

Comment: Possibly related question: [1](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/13744) [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/580344)  [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112698) [4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58500)  [5](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/419372)

Comment: try the method installing with pathogen in link 1 above. // there isn't much information for us to debug, but from the " The archive above will unzip in the following manner:" section in the sourceforge page it appears that you're unzipping into a subfolder, you're supposed to unzip it flat.

Comment: Do any of the `\ll` (compile), `F5` or `F7` (prompt environments/commands) vim-latex commands work?  Have you run `:PlugInstall`?  Installing via vim-plug (as you have are setup to do with `Plug 'vim-latex/vim-latex'`) is the easiest way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the answers!
Dai Bowen, I have made sure that :PlugInstall has been run, and unfortunately the environments commands (F5 and F7) don't work.

user202729, The PlugInstall plugin installer does not work well. I will try pathogen.

Comment: @DaiBowen Have you installed vim-latex with vim-plug alone? Or have you used another tool to manage it, as vim-pathogen? How many plugin installer do we need to run vim properly? What are they?

Comment: @Drosera_capensis I only use vim-plug, there is no need to use multiple (and might be collisions if so).  Unlike Pathogen and Vundle, vim-plug handles the download and installation of packages making it easier and closer to a conventional package manager.  I would suggest starting as close as possible to fresh and trying again only using vim-plug and your linked vimrc.

Comment: @DaiBowen Thank you very much, I will clean a bit my .vim directory and .vimrc and give another try.

Comment: Hopefully accepting indicates you've resolved this, if not feel free to provide more updates/information. Just on the downvote you received, it seems harsh to me, possible reasons might be including your `vimrc` by link (this is not advised as linkrot might render a question unintelligible in the future), and not making it a minimal example (there are some web/python lines that could easily be dropped in troubleshooting), otherwise in my opinion installing vim plugins (even if latex-specific) could be off-topic but verifying the installation of a latex-specific plugin is on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verifying a vim-latex install with <kbd>F9</kbd> is not the best idea as this relies on your vim having been built with python, and a bib file to be found, as your `vimrc` shows you are using an additional citation plugin this could also clash with vim-latex's <kbd>F9</kbd> completion.  Testing compilation with <kbd><Leader>ll</kbd> (this compiles the saved file on disk rather than in vim) or the <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>F7</kbd> keys to insert environments or commands would be a safer bet, e.g. in a blank `tex` file typing `document` then <kbd>F5</kbd> should insert a document template.

vim-latex only loads for files whose filetype is `tex` (while a plugin manager can enforce this, it is a setting baked into vim-latex) and so ensure `:set filetype?` returns `filetype=tex` otherwise vim-latex not being active is expected behaviour.

Otherwise the question is probably whether you are successfully installing the package.  While installation instructions are given for manual installation, installation via a plugin manager such as [Pathogen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112769/106162) or [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) is generally recommended.
`:set runtimepath?` gives some indication of what is getting loaded or with vim-plug `:PlugStatus` indicates both the status and whether a plugin is loaded.

As your `vimrc` shows you are already using vim-plug for other plugins it would be advisable to use that.  Multiple attempted installations could cause clashes and it would be worth clearing as much as possible. It is probably worth starting with only `vim-latex` to avoid any clashes, and verifying that a generic plugin (e.g. [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline)) with no potential overlap can be correctly installed.